# Mutable reference to Vec<_> does not live long enough in while loop

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow

Here's the code so far, the relevant lines are 27 and 28: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=37bba701ad2e9d47741da1149881ddd1

Error message:

```
error[E0597]: `neighs` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:28:25
   |
17 |     while let Some(Reverse(current)) = open.pop() {
   |                                        ---------- borrow later used here
...
28 |         for neighbor in neighs.iter_mut() {
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
38 |     }
   |     - `neighs` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I used Rust a few times in the past, and I'm fully aware of how basic this problem should be. I've also spent hours trying different things and googling similar problems. I just can't seem to find a solution. How do I make `neighs` live as long as function `a_star`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

1. Store copies of Cell in open instead of references to Cell

```
open.push(Reverse(start.clone()));
```

2. Make the parent field of the Cell struct a Box or Rc instead of reference:

```
#[derive(Clone, Eq)]
pub struct Cell {
    coords: (u32, u32),
    g_cost: u32,
    h_cost: u32,
    parent: Option<std::rc::Rc<Cell>>,
}
```

This way open will not reference any of neighs elements or current. which will avoid lifetime issues.

Comment: Thanks! Here's the fix, for anyone interested: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2760b6207ac9e6983906fe67e161e31c

Comment: Generally, when I find myself cloning more than a couple of times in my code, I feel like something's off , but as long as it works, I'm happy! I'd still be interested in finding another workaround that would allow me to contain &Cell in `open`.